Potential Electrical Damage After Connecting Wrong Terminals in Mercedes Benz C350e 2017 (S205)
I own a 2017 Mercedes-Benz C350e (S205). While working on the engine pre-fuse box, I accidentally connected the terminals for the "engine fuse and relay module" and the "on-board electrical system battery connection" (terminals No. 3 and 4 as shown in the diagram). This caused sparks to appear at terminal 3 (engine fuse and relay module), and now the car has no electrical power at all—there is no response to the remote key or the start button.
Where should I look for possible issues or damage?




Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

You accidentally connected 3 and 4 to each other? Or to something else? Or allowed them to touch ground (earth)? Have you done any troubleshooting at all such as disconnect the battery and test all the heavy fuses with an ohmmeter to see which one has blown?

Yes, the 3 and 4 are connected to each other. I checked all the fuses and relays, and they all seem to be working :(

With the battery disconnected, you should completely reassemble the electrical parts to their original configuration, including torquing all nuts that are removed in your photos. Then reconnect the battery to see if everything works normally. There may be a small momentary spark when you reconnect the battery.
